# Grabbing last ten firebase values and assigning them to ten UIButton's titles

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firefox, uibutton

I have been trying to grab the last values at a firebase reference within Xcode using swift and then assigning those 10 values to ten different UIButton's titles. I have tried many things but most of the time nothing happens or i get a crash. I have tried breakpoints but because the code is so small and there are no run0-time errors or warnings it more has to do with how I am doing it( the concept). Any advice would be great and i hope this helps future views with their early iOS and firebase days. Thank you so much for your time and errors!

Below is my latest code which is triggering a crash when the view loads :

```
// import UIKit (already imported the module)

// UIButtons deck1 - deck10 are defined

// firebase reference refName is created

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            var titleArray = [String]()

            var buttonArray : [UIButton:String] = [ // creating a dictionary to make a link from UIButtons to a String that will contain their title

                deck1 : "",
                deck2 : "",
                deck3 : "",
                deck4 : "",
                deck5 : "",
                deck6 : "",
                deck7 : "",
                deck8 : "",
                deck9 : "",
                deck10 : ""

            ]

            refName.queryLimitedToLast(10).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in // getting last

                for child in snapshot.children { // getting the last ten values

                    let title = child.value as String // assigning each value to a variable

                    titleArray.append(title) // adding each variable to an array of values as strings

                }

                buttonArray[self.deck1] = titleArray[0] // assigning each value that is a string in the array 'titleArray' to a UIButton key
                buttonArray[self.deck2] = titleArray[1]
                buttonArray[self.deck3] = titleArray[2]
                buttonArray[self.deck4] = titleArray[3]
                buttonArray[self.deck5] = titleArray[4]
                buttonArray[self.deck6] = titleArray[5] 
                buttonArray[self.deck7] = titleArray[6] 
                buttonArray[self.deck8] = titleArray[7] 
                buttonArray[self.deck9] = titleArray[8] 
                buttonArray[self.deck10] = titleArray[9]

                self.deck1.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck2.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck3.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck4.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck4], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck5.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck5], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck6.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck6], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck7.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck7], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck8.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck8], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck9.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck9], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.deck10.setTitle(buttonArray[self.deck10], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            })

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming deck1 - deck10 are defined as outlets already, try

```
    deck1.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[0]
    deck2.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[1]
    ....
```

So,

```
    // import UIKit (already imported the module)

    // UIButtons deck1 - deck10 are defined

    // firebase reference refName is created

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        var titleArray = [String]()

        refName.queryLimitedToLast(10).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in // getting last

            for child in snapshot.children { // getting the last ten values

                let title = child.value as String // assigning each value to a variable

                titleArray.append(title) // adding each variable to an array of values as strings

            }

        }
    }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

            deck1.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[0] // assigning each value that is a string in the array 'titleArray' to a UIButton key
            deck2.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[1]
            deck3.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[2]
            deck4.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[3]
            deck5.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[4]
            deck6.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[5]
            deck7.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[6]
            deck8.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[7]
            deck9.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[8]
            deck10.titleLabel!.text = titleArray[9]
    }
```

and perhaps some loop can be used instead

Comment: So basically a simpler version of my code but just cutting out what's not needed may work? I'll try that. Thx.

Comment: not sure what your error code is too. post your error?

Comment: there are no run-time errors but a minor crash when the app loads. in a edition to that, the ten button's textLabel is still set to the default of None